# Getting error making a API call(using mergeMap) from the result array of forkJoin and need the combinedResult in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs-observables

Currently I am making 3 different API calls which are below like this:-

```
//API Call1
getUserById(id){
return this.http
      .get(`${environment.userAPI}/user/${Id}`, { headers: this.headers })
      .pipe(
        catchError(err => {
          return throwError(this.errorHandler.handleError(err));
        }),
      );
}
//API Call 2:-
getTeamById(id){
return this.http
      .get(`${environment.TEAM_API}/team/${Id}`, { headers: this.headers })
      .pipe(
        catchError(err => {
          return throwError(this.errorHandler.handleError(err));
        }),
      );
};
////API Call 3:-
getGroupById(id){
return this.http
      .get(`${environment.GROUP_API}/group/${Id}`, { headers: this.headers })
      .pipe(
        catchError(err => {
          return throwError(this.errorHandler.handleError(err));
        }),
      );
};

//Now I am making all the Three API calls at once using forkJoin in the below way:-
forkJoin([getUserById(1), getTeamById(1),getGroupById(1)]).pipe(
      catchError(this.getCatchError)
    )
.subscribe([res1,res2,res3]=>{
  console.log(res1,res2,res3)
})
```

Now I am  having a requirment where using res1 i need to check one condition and make another API call and combine with the above 3 results and my condition is on API call 1 when we get user details i need to check one field team-leader which contains one Id and based on that Id i need to make another API call which is like below:-

```
////API Call 3:-
getLeaderById(id){
return this.http
      .get(`${environment.Leader_API}/leader/${Id}`, { headers: this.headers })
      .pipe(
        catchError(err => {
          return throwError(this.errorHandler.handleError(err));
        }),
      );
};
```

I am achieving the above requirement in the below way:-

```
forkJoin([getUserById(1), getTeamById(1),getGroupById(1)]).pipe(
      catchError(this.getCatchError)
    )
.pipe(
mergeMap(res => 
if(res[0]?.teamLeaderId){
   return getLeaderById(res[0]?.teamLeaderId).//Here I am getting res as undefined
} else{
  return res;
}
)
)
.subscribe([res1,res2,res3,res4]=>{
  console.log(res1,res2,res3,res4);//I am never ever reaching this line of code
})
```

Is there any mistake I am doing? By the end when all API calls are done I need to have 3 results as mandatory and 4th one is optional based on condition.
I am new to RXJS.
**Note:-**
I am using the above code in Angular9 using typescrip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is most likely in the response of the `mergeMap`, the thing that merge map is doing is to return one value to the source observable each time the source emits. In your case with the `forkJoin` operator the source observable emits only once, so you will go just once in the `mergeMap` and as an input argument inside the `mergeMap` you will have the array of 3 responses that are coming from the `forkJoin`.

After that when you go in the if/else block there are two options:

1 If `res[0]?.teamLeaderId == true`
We will return new observable that is the 4-th request and inside the subscribe you will receive only the response from the 4-th request
2 If `res[0]?.teamLeaderId == false` you will return `res` which is not an observable so the source stream will break and throw error.

Here is a working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stack-overflow-combine-forkjoin-with-observable?file=index.ts) that solves your case with `switchMap` and `combineLatest`

```
import { combineLatest, forkJoin, of } from "rxjs";
import { delay, switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";

const observable1 = of(1).pipe(delay(1000));
const observable2 = of(2).pipe(delay(1000));
const observable3 = of(3).pipe(delay(1000));
const observable4 = of(4).pipe(delay(1000));

const condition = true;

const observablen = forkJoin([observable1, observable2, observable3]);
observablen
  .pipe(
    switchMap(x =>
      combineLatest([...x.map(o => of(o)), ...(condition ? [observable4] : [])])
    )
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: value => console.log(value, "True condition"),
    complete: () => console.log("This is how it ends!")
  });

const observablef = forkJoin([observable1, observable2, observable3]);
observablef
  .pipe(
    switchMap(x =>
      combineLatest([
        ...x.map(o => of(o)),
        ...(!condition ? [observable4] : [])
      ])
    )
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: value => console.log(value, "False condition"),
    complete: () => console.log("This is how it ends!")
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your arrow function isn't implemented correctly. Adding braces solves that issue. It may solve the issue you were having ( I haven't bothered replicating the entire issue, so I can't say, leave a comment if it helped out ).

**failing code**

```
mergeMap(res => 
  if(res[0]?.teamLeaderId){
    return getLeaderById(res[0]?.teamLeaderId).//Here I am getting res as undefined
  } else{
    return res;
  }
)
```

**working code**

```
mergeMap(res => {
  if(res[0]?.teamLeaderId){
    return getLeaderById(res[0]?.teamLeaderId).//Here I am getting res as undefined
  } else{
    return res;
  }
})
```